# UK passport for a child born to a UK citizen mother

Tags: eu, passport, uk-citizens

I'm a UK citizen born in Austria (my parents are both UK citizens - father born in the UK and mother in India). I have a British birth certificate and a British passport. I now live in Austria and have given birth to a daughter. Is she entitled to a UK passport?

Comment: have you lived in Austria your entire life?

Comment: What nationality is the other parent?

Comment: No, in Israel and the other parent is Israeli.

Answer (score 5):

So the question is really whether the child is a British citizen, as only British nationals can get a British passport.

From your description, you are a British citizen "by descent", because you were born outside the UK, and you were automatically a British citizen at birth due to your father being born in the UK. As such, you cannot pass on British citizenship at birth to your child born outside the UK, as only British citizens "otherwise than by descent" can do that. In other words, British citizenship only extends automatically to the first generation born abroad.

Under certain circumstances, you can register your child while still a minor to become a British citizen. From the [UK Home Office Guide MN1 (Jan 2017)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/583385/MN1_Guide_January_2017.pdf):

- Section 3(2) registration: This requires that the child have a grandparent who is a British citizen "otherwise than by descent" (which your child has), and that you have lived in the UK for a continuous period of 3 years (during which absences did not exceed 270 days) some time in your life before the child's birth. A child registered under this section becomes a British citizen "by descent".
- Section 3(5) registration: This requires that the child and both parents have lived in the UK for the 3 years immediately prior to application. (In other words, this requires that your family move to the UK first, with the child holding a non-citizen status.) A child registered under this section becomes a British citizen "otherwise than by descent".

Comment: I did not know about the minor registration - that is very relevant to my interests! +1

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very helpful. I was hoping that the fact I have a British Birth Certificate (something which was very important to my parents) will give me some advantage. Unfortunately, I only lived in the UK for 1 year. I also haven't registered in the UK my children or my marital status- is there an added value generally in doing so?

Comment: To get British citizenship, as a minimum requirement the child would have to live in the UK for some time. Some time in the last weeks the UK Home Office decided that a two year old living with two UK citizen "by descent" parents in the UK ought to be removed, which caused some outcry. I don't know if they changed their mind.